# iPhone SE (iOS 10.3.3) - Music stuck on repeat

Tags: iphone, ios, music

The Music app in my iPhone is stuck on looping one song every time, bit like the old repeat setting that has disappeared.

If I play any song as part of shuffle from a Playlist, Artist, All Songs, then that song, when it ends, restarts from the beginning.

I can ask for the next song and that will work fine.  But this looping behavior essentially breaks the app for me as it requires me to fiddle with Music at the end of each song.

I've checked the **Settings**, but nothing really stands out. It's almost as if the **repeat** option which used to exist had been activated.

Restarted iPhone, but no luck.

I would much rather not update to iOS 11.x, since that also seems to have its share of problems.

Comment: Did you check if the repeat is turned on? Refer to [this](http://cdn.iphonehacks.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/shuffle-songs-ios-10-music-app-1.jpg) image to check if repeat is set.

Comment: Aha, you nailed it.  I thought that looked like a familiar fail, but I couldn't find that setting.  GRRRR.  You're right, you need to fiddle with it until you find the `Up Next` view and that's the only place `repeat` shows now.  Txs, I'd definitely accept if you had that as an answer.

Comment: Glad it worked for you :). Let me put it as an answer so it will be helpful to others with similar issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely that the repeat mode is set in the Music app. The repeat mode is still available in the Music app, albeit little hard to locate.

To check for repeat status, in the current playing view, scroll down (as depicted in the image) and check for **repeat** setting.

[image]

**Image Source**: [How To Shuffle Songs in the Music App in iOS 10](http://www.iphonehacks.com/2016/09/shuffle-songs-music-app-ios-10.html)